# In bookdown: avoid wide tables to be cut-off

Tags: r, bookdown, kable, kableextra

When using `bookdown` and rendering a `gitbook`, wide tables are being cut-off to the right.

Try

```
libray(dplyr)
cbind(mtcars, mtcars) %>% 
  knitr::kable(caption = "A wide table")
```

in any `.Rmd` for `bookdown`.

Although in general I find the `kableExtra` package not working very well with `bookdown` (especially `bootrstrap_options` and `full_width`), it seems that we can use `scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "300px")` to allow for wide tables to be displayed correctly.

Sometimes, one would only know if a table is too wide after rendering the document.

**Question**: is there any way that we can depict wide tables without explicitly using the `scroll_box()` option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you output is gitbook only, you can try out `rmarkdown::paged_table`.

Otherwise, you can try to make you scroll_table box not noticeable and use it to every table...

```
library(kableExtra)
kable(cbind(mtcars, mtcars)) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%", box_css = "border: 0px;")
```

For all bookdown multi-format tables, you need to specify `new_session: true` in the `_bookdown.yml` file.

I have an example here https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/bookdown/cross-format-tables-in-bookdown.html#prepare-your-tables-for-all-formats. Note that recent version doesn't require you to specify `options(kableExtra.html.bsTable = T)` anymore. I will change that doc.

Comment: At the moment the output is indeed gitbook only but once I have more experience, I will certainly dive into other outputs as well. Clarfication question: where should `rmarkdown::paged_table` go? In the YAML header? I wrote a function at the beginning of the first `.Rmd` with all `kable_styling()` arguments so that I don't have to specify this all the time (although most arguments such as 'hover' or 'full_width' don't show). I will add your suggestion with the `scroll_box()` as well.

Comment: @Frederick paged_table is just a function similar with kable. I used it all the time when I just want to show some abundant data